# How to use SQL Where to filter words from Select Results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL, how do I filter column values from results of another select statement? In this example, I want to select 'a e f' from tb2 because the result of tb1 is 'a' and 'e'.

UPDATE: clarified my question as it caused some confusion. Also added the example desired result.

Example:

```
select * from (select 'a' as C1 union select 'e' as C1) as tb1

select * from (select 'a b c' as col1
union select 'd e f' as col1
union select 'a e f' as col1) as tb2

============
co1     
a b c   
d e f   
a e f   
============
c1      
a
e
```

after filter only 'a e f' is left because it has both 'a' and 'e'

```
============
c1      
a e f
```

Is this possible with where clause or do I have to create tables to index it somehow?

UPDATE: Tried the first answer but not getting the result I expected.

```
select c1 into #tb1 from (select 'a b c' as c1
union select 'd e f' as col1
union select 'a e f' as col1)
as tb1

select col1 into #tb2 from (select 'a' as col1 union select 'e' as C1) as tb2

select t1.c1, t2.col1  from #tb1 as t1 
left join #tb2 as t2 on t1.c1 like '%' + t2.col1 + '%'
where t2.col1 is null

============
c1      col1
a b c       a
a e f       a
a e f       e
d e f       e
```

Comment: how do I filter column values from results of another select statement

Why not refer only columsn you want in output?

Comment: there's only one column per table here: c1 in tb1 and col1 in tb2. I want to use c1 rows to filter col1 results from tb2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select a.C1 
from tb1 t1 
left join tb2 t2
on t1.C1 like '%' + b.col1 + '%'
where b.col1 is null
```

e.g

```
============              ============
     C1                        col1
============              ============
   abc                          b
   adc                          e
   aec                    ============
============
```

the result will be

```
        ============
            C1
        ============
           adc
```

Updated:

for you want C1 records those are have col1:

```
select distinct a.C1
from tb1 t1
join tb2 t2
on t1.C1 like '%' + b.col1 + '%'
```

some hint about the query:

you can see i delete the where statement and change the left join to inner join(join is default to inner join). so it will filter the records that don't have t2's col1 in tb1's C1. and in the case you give like 'abc','aef','def' t1, 'a','e' t2. you have both 'a' and 'e' in 'aef' so join will give 'aef' twice. use distinct to make it be only 1 records.

Comment: I tested this out and I'm getting a different result. I get no records and if I remove the where statement I get the results.... (in the update section of the question to show code)

Comment: @richterbelmont dude, you sure get no records. you got 'abc','aef','def' in t1 and 'a','e' in t2. the query is help you to get the records that in t1 which don't have the records in t2. you got a or e in every rows in t1, so it's no records.i thought that is what you want, what exactly you want get?

Comment: @richterbelmont and please don't remove the where statement, it's the key part of the filter.

Comment: I actually want the opposite. I want to select the records from t1 that contain the records in t2. It's like a word search where if my keyword (t2) is "quick and "fox", the statement "the quick brown fox" from t1 would match that record. I only removed the where statement because the original query didn't give any results.

Comment: @richterbelmont if you want the opposite, it's easy, just change the where statement is ok. i updated my answer and try it again :)